# How do i install gtkhash to windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, gtk, hashing

My question is about how to install gtkhash to windows 10, as i can't seem to find any guides on how to.

I have tried downloading gtkhash from https://gtkhash.sourceforge.io/
but all i got was a svg file.

Within that file there were some files that described what gtkhash was, but i couldnt find a setup file.

Comment: For Windows you can use the alternative software HashTab e.g. via choco package manager https://chocolatey.org/packages/hashtab

Answer (score 0):

GTKHash does not appear to be written for Windows. It certainly isn't packaged in a way common for Windows programs and there is no documentation stating compatibility with Windows.

Because you can download the source you should be able to compile the application for Windows.

Comment: It would be more like attempt to compile it for Windows, it appears to be a Unix/Linux Utility, so you would have to basically rewrite it in order for it to run on Windows.

Comment: GTK is a cross platform framework, apparently, so it might not be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they did get it compiled for Windows a few months after you asked. Just tested it on Windows 10. *Personally i would use the portable version if you only needed it temporarily due 150Mb of disk space required* Latest release of [GtkHash](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkhash/files/gtkhash/).